# springboot starter dependency versions mismatch

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, maven, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have two different services using same version of springboot (2.0.4) along with `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`. When trying to get the MongoDbFactory instance, the two services are pulling in different versions of `spring-data-mongodb`, one is getting version: `2.0.11.RELEASE`, while other gets version: `2.0.9.RELEASE`.

Same thing reflects in maven dependency tree. Using the same maven for both these projects. Not able to understand how come different versions of `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb` are pulled in. I wanted to update the mongo-driver version to `mongodb-driver-legacy:4.1.0`, which has backward compatibility issue for `spring-data-mongodb` versions prior to `2.0.11.RELEASE`

snippet from pom.xml where it by default  pulls in `spring-data-mongodb` version `2.0.11.RELEASE`:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Here is the snippet from pom.xml file where I have to exlude `spring-data-mongodb`:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Here is the reference output from `mvn dependency:tree`

```
Output from first service:
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.9.RELEASE:compile


Output from second service:
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.0.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.19:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:2.0.11.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.0.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.0.11.RELEASE:compile
```

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml file

Comment: @HeenaTabassum: I have edited the question to add snippets from pom.xml.